# Как реализовать функционал каталога и его вывод на главной сайта Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка

Переношу статику на WP, столкнулся с вопросом вывода ссылок по каталожному типу(с вложенностью) на главной. На данный момент это реализовано так:

[image]

Поясню: есть страницы-родители с прикрепленной картинкой, есть дочерние, сейчас в шаблоне страницы явно через id страницы-родителя получаются ее дети и выводятся.

```
<div class="serviceCard">
<div class="serviceCard__container">
    <? 
       //задаю id страницы-родителя
       $category_post_id = 66; ?>
    <img src="<? echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($category_post_id),full)[0]; ?>" alt="">
    <div class="serviceCard__title">
        <?
        //получаю тайтл родителя и разношу слова по классам
        $title = get_the_title($category_post_id);
        $title_words = explode(' ', $title,2);
        echo $title_words[0];
        ?>
        <div class="serviceCard__title--bold"><? echo $title_words[1]; ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="serviceCard__linksBlock">
        <?
           //получаю все дочерние страницы страницы-родителя
        $childrens = get_children( array(
            'post_parent' => $category_post_id,
            'post_type'   => 'any',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'any'
        ) );
        if( $childrens ){
            //вывожу все ссылки, либо могу ограничить их количество внутри скрипта
            foreach( $childrens as $children ){
                //print_r($children);
                echo ($children->post_type == 'page') ? '<a href="'.get_permalink($children->ID).'" class="serviceCard__link">'.$children->post_title.'</a>' : '';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="animatedFrame serviceCard__frame">
        <div class="animatedFrame__container">
            <div class="animatedFrame__top"></div>
            <div class="animatedFrame__bottom"></div>
            <div class="animatedFrame__left"></div>
            <div class="animatedFrame__right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос: сейчас вывод можно настроить только из файла шаблона страницы. Как сделать так, чтобы управлять выводом (менять количество ссылок, указывать какие ссылки выводить, менять блоки местами) можно было оперативно из админ панели?

PS на данный момент та самая каталожная вложенность реализована через создание страниц и дочерних страниц. Может будут какие-то рекомендации от гуру как это реализовать по-другому?

Comment: Картинки вставляй в вопрос. И инфомусор (приветствия, прощания, спасибы) тоже не нужны. Как и метка [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) Отредактируй вопрос, спросив то, что *реально хочешь узнать*, (а не "реально ли сделать")

Comment: Сама структура через дочерние страницы - нормально. Чтобы удобно менять блоки местами, удобно использовать визуальные редакторы, например, плагин Visual Composer. Создание собственных параметров в админке описано здесь: https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html. Можно сделать чуть проще и выводить дочерние страницы своим шорткодом, в котором задавать число дочерних как параметр. О шорткодах: https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_shortcode

Comment: А так, вопрос слишком общий, конечно.

Comment: Приложите участок используемого кода, сформулируйте четко свою задачу.
Я скорее всего делал бы это используя ACF (Advanced Custom Fields). Вы можете создать поле "Number" и его значение передавать вместо Parent ID, поле "Image" допустим для миниатюр (но это только пример). Очень тяжело понять что вы хотите сделать

Comment: Хотя если примерно присмотреться ко второму блоку, то можно сделать такой вывод: каждый блок - это категория, которая содержит миниатюру, название категории и посты.

Comment: @eugene_v именно так! задуманный функционал - это страница категории с миниатюрой и страницы, которые входят в эту категорию.

Comment: Но Вы должны понимать, если Вы обращаетесь за помощью - люди не должны догадываться, что и как Вы хотите сделать. Нужно подробно описывать картину без "лишней воды"

Comment: Так раз уж вы все-таки меня поняли, подскажите как реализовать желаемый функционал  и вывести категорию с картинкой и страницами данной категории, чтобы можно было управлять порядком вывода и количеством выводимых ссылок для каждой категории?

Comment: Нужно смотреть ваш код, я все описал примерно в 4 комментарии. Обновите свой вопрос, добавив в него участок кода, который отвечает за выборку категорий и постов

Comment: Это код одного блока у вас? Оно не выводится в цикле? Для каждого блока вы будете задавать свой id? Переведите обсуждение на чат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, оттолкнемся от того, что все ваши 6 блоков имеют такой же код и все что от вас требовалось - это поменять ID и вы хотите это редактировать с админки

```
    <div class="serviceCard">
    <div class="serviceCard__container">
        <?
        //задаю id страницы-родителя
        $category_post_id = 66; ?>
        <img src="<? echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($category_post_id),full)[0]; ?>" alt="">
        <div class="serviceCard__title">
            <?
            //получаю тайтл родителя и разношу слова по классам
            $title = get_the_title($category_post_id);
            $title_words = explode(' ', $title,2);
            echo $title_words[0];
            ?>
            <div class="serviceCard__title--bold"><? echo $title_words[1]; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="serviceCard__linksBlock">
            <?
            //получаю все дочерние страницы страницы-родителя
            $childrens = get_children( array(
                'post_parent' => $category_post_id,
                'post_type'   => 'any',
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'post_status' => 'any'
            ) );
            if( $childrens ){
                //вывожу все ссылки, либо могу ограничить их количество внутри скрипта
                foreach( $childrens as $children ){
                    //print_r($children);
                    echo ($children->post_type == 'page') ? '<a href="'.get_permalink($children->ID).'" class="serviceCard__link">'.$children->post_title.'</a>' : '';
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="animatedFrame serviceCard__frame">
            <div class="animatedFrame__container">
                <div class="animatedFrame__top"></div>
                <div class="animatedFrame__bottom"></div>
                <div class="animatedFrame__left"></div>
                <div class="animatedFrame__right"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Установите себе плагин [ACF (Advanced Custom Fields)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/), [документация ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/). C помощью этого плагина создайте кастомные поля, выглядит это примерно так:

1. Задаете заголовок метабоксу: Service Card.
2. Даете заголовок кастомному полю "Field Label": Service Card ID 1, Service Card ID 2 и т.д.
3. "Field Name" сформируется автоматически: service_card_id_1, service_card_id_2 - очень важно этот параметр указывать латиницей, т.к. этот Field Name вы будете использовать в коде.
4. Field Type можете указать "Number" (так будет удобнее).
5. Field Instructions на свое усмотрение (не обязательно, но если кроме вас еще кто-то будет заниматься, то лучше описать значение этого поля).

[image: Custom Field 1]

В секции Location указывает правило `Page - is equal to - Home Page`, это означает, что эти поля будут выводиться только на главной странице. Optino > Style советую поставить `Standard (WP Metabox)` - это не особо важно, но визуально красивее.

[image: Custom Field 2]

В итоге у вас получится вот такая картина

[image: Custom Field 3]

Вот такой результат вы получите на главной странице

[image: Metabox]

Теперь переходим к коду. В каждый из блоков вы передаете значение соответствующего поля `the_field('service_card_id_1')` почему я и говорил, что желательно указывать это на латинице.
Ну в общем все!

```
    <?
        //задаю id страницы-родителя
        $category_post_id = the_field('service_card_id_1'); ?>
```

Единственное, что бы я еще сделал - это проверку. Если у вас случайно в этот поле не будет никакого значения, а мы его не устанавливали по-умолчанию, в таком случае блок не будет отображаться.

```
    <?php if (get_field('service_card_id_1') != '') { ?>
        <div class="serviceCard">
            <div class="serviceCard__container">
            //здесь помещаете код первого блока и так для всех 6 блок
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```